# How can I trigger each link in a list of hyperlinks to animate on click (tap on touchscreens)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list of links to which I don't want to apply any animation on hover but do want to apply an "outro" animation on click. I've got the animation to do what I want it to do, but clicking on any link moves the entire list as a unit, which, of course, is not the point of a list of links. I'm sure this requires a simple jquery tweak, but I can barely read jquery, much less write it. If someone can tell me why this is going wrong (and how to fix it), I would be grateful. Here're the deets:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="stage">
   <ul class="all-links">
     <li class='each-link'><a class="thankyou" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Google</a></li>
     <li class="each-link"><a class="thankyou" href="https://wikipedia.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Wikipedia</a></li>
     <li class="each-link">
       <a class="thankyou" href="https://goodreads.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Goodreads</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #c4a278;
}

.stage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 5%; 
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


ul.all-links {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflowX:hidden;
}

.each-link {
   position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

a.thankyou {
 color: #762500;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.road-runner {
    animation: beep-beep 2.51s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes beep-beep {
   0% {
  left: 0%
  }
  
  4% {
    transform: translateY(-1vh);
  }
  
  8% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  12% {
    transform: translateY(-1vh);
  }
  
  16% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    left: 0%;
  }
  
  21% {
   transform: skewX(0deg); 
  }
  
  25% {
    transform: skewX(-40deg);
  }
  
  100% {
   left: 100%;
    transform: skewX(-40deg);
  }
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            $(".each-link").addClass("road-runner");
        });


        $('.each-link').on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
             $(this).removeClass("road-runner");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I would like the link to stay "offstage" for several seconds before returning to its original place in the list. Currently, it pops back to the left as soon as it finishes the animation.  thanks again.

Comment: You should be able to modify your keyframe timings to do so.

Comment: OK, that works, too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selects all links on your entire webpage. Probably not what you want.

```
$("a")
```

Fix:

```
// Select every anchor with a parent that has the "each-link" class.
$(".each-link a").click(function() {
  // Add class to the the parent of the currently clicked link with "each-link" class.
  $(this).closest(".each-link").addClass("road-runner");
});
```

Comment: That's it! I knew it'd be simple for someone who spoke jquery. Thanks a lot. I have one other quick question if you don't mind. Despite setting the animation-fill-mode to forwards, it returns to the starting position immediately after the animation finishes. Needless, to say (even though I am), I'd prefer it stay "offstage" while the new page loads. (I've set a page load delay to give the outro time to do its thing). I've hacked a workaround by making the animation reach left: 100%; at 50% and then run all the way to 1000% to kill time. But is there a jquery script that can do this instead?

Comment: fill forwards isn't doing its job because you remove the road-runner class after the animation ends...

Comment: Of course! I should have surmised that despite being jquery-challenged. Thank you again.